# How to use 'case when' and 'substr' to update a column in oracle sql?

Tags: sql, case, oracle-sqldeveloper, substr

I have a dataset which looks something like this:

| Category | Name |
| --- | --- |
| T-1029-PHONE | sjss |
| T-2629172-LAPTOP | ssus |
| T-26124-PC | udia |
| T-22 |  |
| T-1029-PHONE |  |
| T-1029 |  |

I want to update the 'Name' column by getting the last part of the 'Category' value string after the second '-' to get the table to look something like this:

| Category | Name |
| --- | --- |
| T-1029-PHONE | PHONE |
| T-2629172-LAPTOP | LAPTOP |
| T-26124-PC | PC |
| T-22 |  |
| T-1029-PHONE | PHONE |
| T-1029 |  |

I have already used this statement:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(Category, INSTR(Category, '-', 1,2)+1) AS Category 
FROM Tech_table;
```

This statement gets the last part of the string after the second dash however, I want to use a 'CASE WHEN' statement so that it will only look at the values in the 'Category' column where the format is like "%-%-%" such as 'T-1029-PHONE' and all the other ones in this same format, but not looking at the rows where the Category only has 1 dash such as 'T-1029'. Only when the format is like "%-%-%" in 'Category' then the 'Name' column values should update but when the Categories are not "%-%-%" then the 'Name' column for those Categories should not be updated but should remain the same.

Is there a way I can update my 'Name' column using a SELECT SUBSTR with a CASE WHEN statement for the scenario above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update tech_table
set name = SUBSTR(Category, INSTR(Category, '-', 1,2)+1)
where category like '%-%-%'
```

Comment: Thats perfect, thank you so much! Didnt realise it was that simple and I didnt need to use a CASE WHEN :)